# Jersey dependency conflict

Tags: java, maven, jersey-2.0

I'm implementing a [dropwizard](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.2.2/docs/) server app on top of an existing project. building with maven.

I'm currently in jar hell, and it's not fun. I have a pom file that's rather convoluted. I have a big problem with jersey dependencies packaged with hadoop/glassfish/com.sun. `com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar1.19` is conflicting with `org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.22.2`. I tried adding some exclusions to make it use the `2.22.x` version, but it's still giving me the error seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34136774/dropwizard-application-crashed-by-abstractjaxbprovider). I've been combing through the dependency tree and adding exclusions where I see fit, but can't seem to get it right. Here is my [pom file](https://pastebin.com/PCJFJSNC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personal experience tells me that you should check ALL your dependencies (especially the ones you developed in-house) if you have the old jersey version as a dependency in there.

That's what solved a similiar problem for me.

Comment: `mvn dependency:list | grep jersey` will spit out the dependencies pulling in jersey. Hadoop was using an old version of jersey that I then excluded in the pom file that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you do :

**mvn dependency:list -Dverbose** 
   (grep for filtering results)

it gives u the list of dependencies(transitive ones also).Check the version of sun jersey or glassfish jersey that's being used in your application.

If you do :

**mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=jersey-server**

you will see the graph of where any version of jersey-server is coming from a parent.

I had a hadoop-client and an in-house rest-bus-client using a version of sun jersey(1.9.x) which i needed to remove. I tried  in maven and it simply worked.

Also, this jersey version unmatch caused the following issue for me in dropwizard.

[java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45187624/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-ws-rs-core-application-getpropertiesljava-u)